# java to kotlin Type mismatch

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i try to convert   the given java(below) code to Kotlin but stuck at some point ,showing 
an error  **Type mismatch**

this is the java code i would try to convert to kotlin

```
public void insert(List<UserPreference> userPreferences,InsertCallback callback ){
        ioExecutor.execute(()->
        {
            userPrefDao.insert(userPreferences);
            callback.insertFinished();
        });
    }
```

```
 @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<UserPreference> userPreferences) {

        localCache.insert(userPreferences,()-> {  lastRequestedPage++;
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: inserted");
            isRequestInProgress = false;});


    }
```

this is the kotlin code i invented but get an error type mismatch

```
fun insert(userPreferences: List<UserPreference>, callback: InsertCallback) {
        ioExecutor.execute({
            userPrefDao.insert(userPreferences)
            callback.insertFinished()
        })
    }
```

```
   override fun onSuccess(userPreferences: List<UserPreference>) {

        localCache.insert(userPreferences, {
            lastRequestedPage++
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: inserted")
            isRequestInProgress = false
        })


    }
```

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
UserPrefLocalCache.InsertCallback
Found:
() → Unit
```

How to fix this please help me

Comment: Use `localCache.insert(userPreferences, object :InsertCallback{
           //////
        })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java supports *functional interfaces* (interfaces with one non-default, non-static method) to be instantiated using lambda expressions. Kotlin doesn't have this relation.

You can either instantiate the interface on its own, using object literals:

```
localCache.insert(userPreferences, object : InsertCallback {
    override fun ...
})
```

Or, you directly use a functional type in Kotlin:

```
typealias InsertCallback = () -> Unit

localCache.insert(userPreferences) {
    // lambda here
}
```

If `InsertCallback` is still a Java interface, you can instantiate it using SAM conversions. This does not work for Kotlin interfaces.

```
localCache.insert(userPreferences, InsertCallback {
    // lambda here
})
```